# How to bind user control property to other property?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have the following user control:

The Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScreenRecorder.TimePicker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="27" Width="176">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox  Width="150" Height="25" Text="{Binding Time}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button Width="25" Height="12.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnKeyUp_Clicked">
                <Image Source="up.png" Height="10" Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Width="25" Height="12.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnKeyDown_Clicked">
                <Image Source="down.png" Height="10" Width="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The Code:

```
 public partial class TimePicker : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        //Time = m_time;
    }

    public static DependencyProperty TimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Time", typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker));

    //private string m_time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    public string Time
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TimeProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }

    private void btnKeyUp_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime curTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Time);
        curTime += new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Time = curTime.ToString();
    }

    private void btnKeyDown_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime curTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Time);
        curTime -= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Time = curTime.ToString();
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And I have another user control that uses this user control as follow:

```
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Begin Record Time" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
            <local:TimePicker Time="{Binding StartRecordTime}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

StartRecordTime looks like this:

```
public string StartRecordTime
    {
        get { return m_startRecord; }
        set
        {
            m_startRecord = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StartRecordTime");
        }
    }
```

I want to change the StartRecordTime according to the Time Property and vice versa, but only the Time property is changing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding won't work as you've set the `DataContext` of `TimePicker` to `TimePicker` itself.  You'll notice a binding error in the Output window:

> BindingExpression path error: 'StartRecordTime' property not found on 'object' ''TimePicker' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=StartRecordTime; DataItem='TimePicker' (Name=''); target element is 'TimePicker' (Name=''); target property is 'Time' (type 'String')

I'd suggest to have a more 'sane' experience you remove `DataContext = this` from the `TimePicker` constructor and set the Grid's `DataContext` to the `TimePicker` by Element Name.  Add a name attribute to the `UserControl` element:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Root" ...
```

And set the `DataContext` of the `Grid`:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}">
```

This will be inherited by all child elements.  You will also need to change your binding to `TwoWay`, either explicitly:

```
<local:TimePicker Time="{Binding Path=StartRecordTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Or by setting this as the default in the `DependencyProperty` registration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Time", typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

I'd also note that there's no reason for `TimePicker` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I suggest you remove this.

Comment: @Joe Was there any part of my answer you didn't follow? Do you have a Binding error in your Output window?  I've reproduced your issue using your code, the above is the cause and the changes will fix it.

Comment: I did follow all the instructions you said but still not working, maybe i'm missing something, i'll check it.

Comment: Hi, I've created a new simpler program about what i need. I've implement your suggestions but still can't get the result i need i've uploaded the program: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9yk1h2z8yyo2e7/UserControlPropertyTransfer.rar?dl=0  it would be great if you can help what am i doing wrong. Thank you for your time

Comment: The issue in your sample is your `MainWindow` has no `DataContext` set, so the binding isn't used.  Setting `DataContext = this` in `MainWindow` is the simplest fix, though I'd suggest using a ViewModel instead.  Perhaps you can apply this to your original problem?  You don't explicitly say where `StartRecordTime` is, I had (perhaps incorrectly) assumed this was all straight forward.

Comment: you right i forgot the DataContext = this, and it's worked. the StartRecordTime is inside of Record class the datacontext for the other user control is bind to record class: public partial class RecordTimerConfiguration : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged { private Entities.Record m_record = new Entities.Record(); public RecordTimerConfiguration() { InitializeComponent(); this.DataContext = m_record; }}  but it still not working. what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<local:TimePicker Time="{Binding Path=StartRecordTime, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but it didn't work, if it can help the  PropertyChanged of the StartRecordTime id null but when i replace the user control to textbox the PropertyChanged of the StartRecordTime is not null, i don't know why.